# ld can't map file errno=22 for architecture armv7

Tags: iphone, ios, build, arm, llvm-gcc

When command line building a project for iPhone (iOS) I get the following error:

> ld can't map file errno=22 for architecture armv7

However, when checking libraries and objects via lipo - info they support armv7.  Has anyone had this issue and/or know how to get the link to complete?

Answer (score 1):

err=22 means "Invalid argument passed to ld"

In your logs, you'll see a massive long line above the error line, which is the ACTUAL arguments passed to ld. You need to examine this carefully, work out what each part means, work out the bit where Xcode has gone wrong, and deal with it.

DEFAULT ASSUMPTION: it's probably a filename that has unsupported characters (or a name that contains spaces and doesn't have "" around it). If so, that's a bug in ld - but also a bug in Xcode that it's allowing the characters in first place.

Answer (score -1):

You need all the static libraries you use in your iOS project to be compiled for armv7. If they're not, it may work on the simulator, but will never work on the device.

Comment: Yes, they are all compiled & support armv7, but I'm currently only building for iPhone.  It will run in a terminal app, so the simulator seemed to have limited utility here.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: You shouldn't need this at all. Until today, Xcode's toolchain was happily saying "ignoring file for wrong architecture X". Today, for no reason, a project stopped building, spouting out the above error. Since Apple provides no way of manually selecting which library to build, I believe this answer is incorrect: Apple's design is that Xcode/compiler/linker *automatically* excludes files of wrong arch.

Comment: Confirmed: I removed all static libs for the project, and the error remains. This answer is incorrect.